# Is there a $(\mathfrak{c},\mathfrak{c})$-gap in $\omega^{\mathfrak{c}}$?

Tags: set-theory

On page 580 of Jech there is a section on functions from $\omega_1$ to $\omega$.  I am interested in families of these functions, and also families in the set $\omega^{\mathfrak{c}}$.  Do $(\omega_1, \omega_1)$-gaps exist in $ \omega^{\omega_1} $?  Similarly, do $(\mathfrak{c},\mathfrak{c})$-gaps exist in $\omega^{\mathfrak{c}} $? I am thinking that the definition of gaps would slightly change in this context, as the function which fills a pregap is in $\omega^{\omega_1}$ and $\omega^{\mathfrak{c}} $, respectively.

My general question is: does making the length of the individual members of the families ''longer'' have an effect on Hausdorff gap results?

By the way, my definition of ordering is this (which seems different from the ordering in Jech for functions from $\omega$ to $\omega_1$) :

For $f: \mathfrak{c} \to \omega$ and $g: \mathfrak{c} \to \omega$ define $f < g$ if $f(\alpha) < g(\alpha)$ for all but countably many $\alpha < \mathfrak{c}$.

For example, let $f(\alpha)=1$ when $\alpha$ is even and less than $\omega$, let $f(\alpha) = 0$ when $\alpha$ is odd and less than $\omega$ and define $f(\alpha) = 2$ for all $\alpha$ greater than or equal to $\omega$.  And let $g(\alpha)$ be 0 on the evens and 1 on the odds, and 3 for every $\alpha \ge \omega$.  Then $f < g$ in this ordering.

Comment: There are no infinite decreasing sequences in $\omega^{\omega_1}$, since the co-bounded filter on $\omega_1$ is $\sigma$-complete. Similarly for $\omega^{\mathfrak{c}}$, since $\mathfrak{c}$ does not have countable cofinality.

Comment: Oh, wait I think I see what you are saying. Thank you Johannes.